# Casting struct fails with: ... is not convertible to

Tags: swift, struct, casting

I have a protocol:

```
protocol Occurrence {
    var isEmpty: Bool { get }
    mutating func addOccurrence(occ: Occurrence) -> Occurrence
    mutating func removeOccurrence(occ: Occurrence) -> Occurrence
}
```

And a struct that conforms to that protocol:

```
struct NonEmptyOccurrence: Occurrence, Printable {

    ...
    private var _occurrence: Int

    var isEmpty: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        }
    }

    ...

    mutating func addOccurrence(other: Occurrence) -> Occurrence {
        if other.isEmpty {
            return self
        } else {
            //error here: Occurrence is not convertible to NonEmptyOccurrence
            _occurrence = _occurrence + (other as NonEmptyOccurrence)._occurrence 
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

In the `addOccurrence` method there is an error as I put it to the comment. What am I missing here? Why can't I cast that instance to NonEmptyOccurrence?

Comment: Consider what would happen if you had a completely separate type that also conforms to `Occurrence`, but is neither a `NonEmptyOccurence` nor any struct based on it... what should the compiler do? How can it cast it to `NonEmptyOccurence`?

Comment: @Grimxn that sounds logical, but the complier could let me try to cast it, and fail at runtime as with classes. Basically my question is that is casting is failable with classes, but not allowed with structs?

Comment: Well, a protocol generally can apply to a class as well as a struct (not in your case, as your template contains a `mutable func`), so I guess they just don't allow it. What you could try is something like `var temp = NonEmptyOccurence()` and set `temp._occurrence` to `other._occurrence`'s value. Can't see your `init`s so can't tell you exactly how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that you can cast structs in Xcode 6 beta3, but you cannot in the current stable version (Xcobe 6.2).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
mutating func addOccurrence(other: Occurrence) -> Occurrence {
    if !other.isEmpty, let otherAsNEO = (other as? NonEmptyOccurrence) {
        _occurrence = _occurrence + otherAsNEO._occurrence 
    }
    return self
}
```